# Intuition behind the local limit theorem in hyperbolic groups

Tags: pr.probability, geometric-group-theory, limits-and-convergence, random-walks, intuition

Let $\Gamma$ be a finitely generated group and let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\Gamma$. Denote by $X_n$ the induced random walk. Finally, let $p_n=\mu^{*n}(e)=P_e(X_n=e)$. The local limit problem consists of finding precise asymptotics of $p_n$. In hyperbolic groups, we have the following.

**Theorem** Let $\Gamma$ be a Gromov-hyperbolic group and let $\mu$ be a symmetric finitely supported probability measure on $\Gamma$, whose support generates $\Gamma$. Then, there exists $C\geq 0$ and $R>1$ such that
$p_n\sim CR^{-n}n^{-3/2}$, $n\to \infty$.

This is due to [Gerl-Woess](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01000210) and [Lalley](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2244712?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) for free groups and to [Gouëzel](https://www.math.sciences.univ-nantes.fr/~gouezel/articles/higherAncona.pdf) in full generality.

**Question** What is the intuition behind the exponent $3/2$ ?

Here is a heuristic explanation in the particular case of the simple random walk on the free group $F(a,b)=F_2$ with two generators $a$ and $b$, that is $\mu=\frac{1}{4}(\delta_a+\delta_{a^{-1}}+\delta_b+\delta_{b^{-1}})$. Then, at each step, the random walk $X_n$ has three chances over four to move away from the identity $e$ and one chance over four to go back closer to $e$. Thus, intuitively, $X_n$ can be compared with the non-centered random walk $Z_n$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ driven by the measure $\frac{3}{4}\delta_1+\frac{1}{4}\delta_{-1}$. When looking at $X_n$ going away or closer to $e$, we only care about the distance between $e$ and $X_n$, so we actually have to compare $X_n$ to the random variable $Z_n^+$, which is the random variable $Z_n$ conditioned on staying positive. Now, the local limit theorem on non-centered random walk assigned to stay positive in $\mathbb{Z}$ is indeed of the form $CR^{-n}n^{3/2}$, see [there](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0406182.pdf).

However, there is an obvious problem with this intuition : when looking at the distance $d(e,X_n)$, you do not get independent random variables, so it's not clear if one can make a rigorous statement comparing $X_n$ and $Z_n^+$.

Also, it's not clear how to give such a heuristic argument in general hyperbolic groups (except very vaguely saying that the random walk should behave like in a tree).